# URL with escaped urls as parameters in Titanium. Getting exception only in Android

Tags: javascript, android, escaping, titanium

I'm working in a Titanium project and we are using mapbox to get the map images. With mapbox we can also use another remote image for the map marker. Also this images are cached in cloudinary.
So the the code to create the url is:

```
    url    = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/id/image/fetch/';
    marker = 'url-' + encodeURIComponent(markerImageURL) + '(' + longitude + ',' + latitude + ')/';
    url    = url + encodeURIComponent('http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/blabla.key/' + marker + longitude + ',' + latitude + ',18/' + mapWidth + 'x' + mapHeight + '.png');

    $.mapImage.setImage(url);
```

The structure of the url is something like:

```
    http://res.cloudinary.com/id/image/fetch/[escaped-mapbox-url]
```

Where [mapbox-url]:

```
    http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/user/url-[escaped-marker-url]/longitude,latitude,zoom/widthxheight.png
```

And [escaped-marker-url]:

```
    url-marker(longitude,latitude)/
```

**In IOS this works flawlessly but in Android this get me the following error:**

```
    [ERROR] TiDownloadManager: (pool-4-thread-1) [77094,82061] Exception downloading [Here puts the plain url, not the escaped version]
    [ERROR] TiDownloadManager: java.io.FileNotFoundException: [Here puts the plain url, not the escaped version]
    [ERROR] TiDownloadManager:  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:186)
    [ERROR] TiDownloadManager:  at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:462)
    [ERROR] TiDownloadManager:  at org.appcelerator.titanium.util.TiDownloadManager$DownloadJob.run(TiDownloadManager.java:135)
    [ERROR] TiDownloadManager:  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    [ERROR] TiDownloadManager:  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    [ERROR] TiDownloadManager:  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I have tried escaping it with escape(), encodeUri(), put in plain text also escaped the () , - . characters but nothing seems to work. Some clues are appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried using `Ti.Network.encodeURIComponent`? http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network-method-encodeURIComponent

Comment: Yeah, but still no luck.